# How does PasteWSGIServer handle concurrent request

Tags: python, concurrency, paster

I'm really confused on how Paste server handles concurrent request.
I have a bottle framework, and bottle provides a parameter to switch to other servers to gain efficiency.

However, I'm not able to understand how Paste server works.
Gunicorn use pre-fork to create multiple processes.
Gevent server is coroutine.

But I can't figure out how Paste server works.

In the official [Paste Server site](https://paste.readthedocs.io/en/latest/paste-httpserver-threadpool.html), it describes concurrent request is handled by **Thread Pool**.

Then I assume the Paste server will create a process pool to handle all the requests.

I tried to check the running processes while Paste Server is handling multiple requrests:

`ps -ef | grep python`

I can only find one Paste Server process alone.

Can anyone tell me how does Paste server handle concurrent requests? Or is there any document describes how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was included in your question:

> In the official Paste Server site, it describes concurrent request is handled by Thread Pool.
>
> Then I assume the Paste server will create a process pool to handle all the requests.

Don't assume process pool, documentation clearly says otherwise. `ps -efL` to see threads.

Comment: Thanks a lot temoto! I thought that Python does not support multi-thread because of the Global Interpreter Lock. So when I see multi-threading my mind automatically translated it to multi-processing :(. Now I understand multi-threading could be useful in heavy IO situation that's why Paste implemented this multi-threading module. Thanks a lot!